# python remove ctrl-character from string

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing

I have a bunch of XML files dumped to disk in batches.
When I tried to prase them I found that some hade a control character inserted into an attribute.

It looked like this:

```xml
<root ^KIND="A"></root>
```

When it was supposed to look like this:

```xml
<root KIND="A"></root>
```

Now in this case it was easily fixed, just some regexp magic:

```py
import re
xml = re.sub(r'<([^>]*)\v([^>]*)>', r'<\1K\2>', xml)
```

But then the requirements changed, I had to dump the docs out to disk, individually.
Naturally I raw the substitution before saving so i wouldn't have that problem again.

There are alot of these documents you see, many millions...

And so, I was getting ready to extract some data from them again.

This time however I got a new error:

```xml
<root KIND="A"><CLASSIFICATION></CLASSIFICATIO^N></root>
```

When it was supposed to look like this:

```xml
<root KIND="A"><CLASSIFICATION></CLASSIFICATION></root>
```

I am not sure why I keep getting these errors not why its always 'ctrl-characters` that are inserted. It migth be that its pure luck so far.

The regexp I used in hte first case wont wore in general, ^K translates to vertical tab so I could match agains that. But is there some what to filter out any ctrl-character?

Comment: Schouldnt you look into the thing that dumps those files? Who is responsible for that piece of code and how does it look? why does it put "control characters" into the xml to begin with? I only know of Escaped characters - what _are_ control characters btw? CTRL is just a key-modifier - it leaves no "trace" if in a file.

Comment: Hey, I am the one dumping them. The ctrl modifier isnt inserted on purpose, it just shows up. the dumpint process just saves a string to disk using gzip

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess ... that looks like you got some menu-structure and the ^ denotes what shortcutkey can reach this menu - like: Alt+K to activate the root thingy and Alt+N to activate the classification - buy why is one in the opening XML TAg and the other in the closing one .. this is quite unanswerable me thinks.

Comment: Well if you are: [mre] of the code that lets us replicate the problem

Comment: well, dumping 1 million xml resultet in 999 999 documents that where fine, and one that wasnt, the ctrl character wasnt in the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a translate table to get rid of ctrl-A through ctrl-Z:

```
in_chars = ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(1, 27)])
out_chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
tr_table = str.maketrans(in_chars, out_chars)

# pass all strings through the translate table:
x = input('Enter text: ')
print(x.translate(tr_table))
```

Prints:

```
Enter text: abc^Kdef
abcKdef
```